# Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found. (again)

Tags: support, openid, login

I see this message when I try to log in from the main site:

> ### Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> ### No OpenID endpoint found.

Meta and three other network sites continue working fine (I guess my login token has not expired there). Trying to log in from other sites with expired tokens bring up the same exact message.

My Open ID provider is livejournal. I logged out and back in on their site to make sure that it's not likely a problem with their site.